# Por que no puedo hacer reservas desde el admin panel con mas de tres meses de anticipacion en hotel booking de motopress

Tags: php, wordpress

alguien que me ayude por favor, tengo una pagina web en wordpress donde se realizan reservas a traves del plugin hotel booking de motopress, y cuando quiero realizar una reserva desde el admin panel con tres meses de anticipacion no me aparecen reservas disponibles, porfa si alguien sabe la solucion, le agradeceria su ayuda.

intente cambiar en la configuracion del plugin el tiempo maximo de anticipacion para hacer reservas y aun no funciona

Comment: Lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].